# Two if statements in parallel assigning value to same variable in Verilog, what is the precedence then?

Tags: if-statement, verilog, system-verilog, hdl

Let's say we have these two `if` conditions assigning values to the same variable and both `if` statements can be true at the same time. What value will x have? Lets say z and y are equal to 0.

From my testing in simulator, the `if` statement that was written lower in the code had precedence. The value of x was 1 when I simulated the code below with values of z and y equal to 0. When I had the `if` conditions swapped (the `if` condition with "!z" came at the end), then the value of x came out to be 0 in the simulation.

Is there a rule when such a condition happens in Verilog?

```
always @ (posedge clk) begin
  x <= 1'b0;

  if (!z) begin
    x <= 0;
  end

  if (!y) begin
    x <= 1;
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules for all Verilog behavior are set in the IEEE Std 1800-2017.  Section 9.3.1 *Sequential blocks*, states:

```
A sequential block shall have the following characteristics:
  — Statements shall be executed in sequence, one after another.
```

In this context, a sequential block is defined by the `begin/end` keywords.

Also, section 10.4.2 *Nonblocking procedural assignments*:

> The order of the execution of distinct nonblocking assignments to a
> given variable shall be preserved.

However, it is much more common to write your code so that each nonblocking assignment is unambiguous.

```
always @ (posedge clk) begin
    if (!y) begin
        x <= 1;
    end else if (!z) begin
        x <= 0;
    end else begin
        x <= 0;
    end
end
```

When this code is simulated, only one of the 3 assignments will be executed.